# High Power BJT Current mirror

Tags: power, current, bjt, power-consumption, current-mirror

I am trying to find an example of BJT current mirror with high power consumption. Any advice concerning the setup , or an example design will be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). State what are you hoping to achieve rather than what you believe the solution to be.

Comment: Here is the question: Come up with an example concerning a current reference/mirror where a preference for BJT upsets the partitioning of your power budget.

Comment: *BJT current mirror with high power consumption* What does that even mean? What is "high power consumption", in an application which runs on harvested energy, a current mirror running on 1 mA can be considered "high power" but in a 5G RF PA, a mirror using 1 mA isn't considered to use a lot of power. As is your question cannot be answered. I agree with Andy that you should explain what you want to achieve instead of asking for specific circuits.

Comment: Just shared the original version. Sorry for the confusion I caused.

Comment: *Come up with an example concerning a current reference/mirror where a preference for BJT upsets the partitioning of your power budget.* Then include that in the question! (use the Edit function). And then your question will be downvoted as "Homework without any shown effort to solve". We don't "do" your homework here. *Sorry for the confusion I caused* To prevent that: 1) read the **help** 2) just follow this site for a while and learn what type of questions are downvoted and which are not.

Comment: See that's exactly why I did not asked the original question and asked for advice on how should I design it.

Comment: Then analyze the question and figure out what that means for the circuit. It's a simple current mirror so how many parameters of freedom do you have?

Comment: I wouldn't have asked if that was easy for me.

Comment: Then get studying to learn : *how many parameters of freedom do you have to design a current mirror. What are a current mirror's properties?*.

Comment: Thank you will delete the post

Comment: What frequency response? What compliance can you live with? What errors can you tolerate? What range of currents? What range of power supply voltages? What circuit impedance does the output feed into? What range of input currents are required? What current magnification factor do you need?

Comment: First google some stuff, then ask about more specific matters and provide details... This question is too broad.